# FMU-module method get_variable_unit() and more

Tags: python, fmi, jmodelica

Since FMI version 2.0 we have methods: get_variable_unit() and get_variable_display_unit() that brings the information from the Modelica code for the FMU-module. What I can see there is no impact on what you obtain from get_variable_data() from the FUM-module on the results from a simulation.

Is there any python-package today that facilitate consistent handling of units in diagrams showing simulated data with JModelica, similar to what you get in for instance OpenModelica in the graphical user interface there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My contact at Modelon says that they welcome third party to contribute here. Perhaps more interesting now to do since PyFMI is on GitHub since end of 2019.